# Maven module dependency and resources

Tags: maven, maven-resources-plugin

I have a maven Project say ProjectA, and there is a class say ClassA in this project which uses the files from resource folder, I am using following way to read from resource:

```
String fileName = IPToGeoMapper.class.getResource("/resourceFile.txt").getFile();
File resourceFile = new File(fileName);
```

and it works like charm.

Now, when I create artifact out of this project (I have tried extracting the created jar and it has resourceFile.txt packed in the jar), and use that as a dependency in other project say ProjectB, ClassA no more finds the resourceFile.txt as it tries to browse though resources folder of ProjectB.

I want the best global solution which will work in all the projects where I import artifact created from ProjectA
What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Try loading it from the class path using ResourceAsStream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way , I am taking an example of reading a property file.

`Properties propfile = new Properties();
                propfile.load(PropertyUtils.class.getClassLoader()
                        .getResourceAsStream(
                                "applicationprops.properties"));`

`BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClassA.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.txt")));
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println(out.toString());   //Prints the string content read from input stream
        reader.close();`

Comment: yeah, I think this will work for properties file as its returning stream, I need handle to the File actually.

Comment: You can still read the file contents from stream. If you will have to read the file contents, edited my answer with reading a file content from stream.